# About cookie expiration

Tags: cookies

If I set cookie to expire in 1 month.

But during that month,I visit the site every day.

Will the cookie still expire after 1 month?

Answer (score 3):

The expiration date is stored in the cookie as a simple date, like 25th Dec 2009. You will have to recreate that cookie (in other words to renew it), if you do not want it to expire after the first month.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you set your cookie - if you set it according to the algorithm:

```
expiration date = today date + 30 days
```

then yes, every visit (assuming you recreate the cookie every time) will of course result in cookie expiration date being extended. If you have some conditions on which the cookie is not recreated (e.g. only checking if it exists), it might be the other way. For more detailed advice you should post a sample of your code.